# Juice UI asp.net webforms adding via code behind

Tags: asp.net, juice-ui

I'd like to integrate the spinner into an ASP.net app I have. I dynamically render controls based on database records and I do so via code behind. I'm having issues adding the spinner in a test project in VS 2012

```
        Label IKnowWhatIKnow = new Label();
        IKnowWhatIKnow.AssociatedControlID = "_Text";
        IKnowWhatIKnow.Text = "ASP.NET Textbox";
        IKnowWhatIKnow.ID = "_Text";

        Juice.Spinner Mine1 = new Juice.Spinner();
        Mine1.ID ="_TextSpinner";
        Mine1.TargetControlID = "_Text"; 
        Mine1.AutoPostBack = true;

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(IKnowWhatIKnow);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(Mine1);
```

I get

Extender control '_TextSpinner' cannot extend '_Text'. Extender controls of type 'Juice.Spinner' cannot extend controls of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward, you need to choose a `TargetControlID` that resolves to something besides a `Label`, like this:

```
<asp:label id="_Label" AssociatedControlId="_Text" Text="ASP.NET Textbox" runat="server" /> 
<asp:textbox ID="_Text" runat="server" />
<juice:spinner TargetControlID="_Text" ID="_TextSpinner" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"/>

<br/><br/>

<label for="_Content__Input">Html Input</label>
<input type="text" id="_Input" runat="server"/>
<juice:spinner TargetControlID="_Input" ID="_InputSpinner" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Brew](http://shellscape.org/#brew) which doesn't have those limitations.